# Appearances wallpaper changes on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, desktop-background

On a fresh download I started getting different wallpapers at each time I opened the box.
Found this in **Appearances**
"Changes through the day"

I have not experienced this before on 14.04

**HOW do I disable it?**

It is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to **System Settings → Appearance** and select any static wallpaper.

Those changing throughout the day have a little white clock symbol on their preview icon.